# Vuex action is not recognized as a function inside component's data()

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am having an issue with triggering a method in the vue component. I am using Element UI with Vuex, and would like to trigger a state change (make another component visible) when a shortcut in the datetimepicker element is clicked. Here's the component code:

```
<template>
    <div id="DateTimePicker">
        <div/>
        TimeInterval state: {{this.$store.getters.timeInterval}}
        <div/>
        <el-date-picker
            :value="this.timeInterval"
            @input="this.setTimeInterval"
            type="datetimerange"
            :picker-options="dateTimeShortcuts"
            range-separator="To"
            format="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
            editable
            time-arrow-control
            start-placeholder="Start date"
            end-placeholder="End date"
            align="right"
            size="large">
        </el-date-picker>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {
    name: 'DateTimePicker',
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters(['timeInterval']),
    },
    methods: {
        ...mapActions(['setTimeInterval', 'setRefreshRateVisibility']),
    },
    data() {
        return {
            dateTimeShortcuts: {
                disabledDate(date) {
                    return date > new Date() || date < new Date('12/1/18');
                },
                shortcuts: [
                    {
                        text: '15 Minutes',
                        onClick(picker) {
                            this.setRefreshRateVisibility(true); // Vue does not recognize this as a function
                            const end = new Date();
                            const start = new Date();
                            start.setTime(start.getTime() - 900 * 1000);
                            picker.$emit('pick', [start, end]);
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
        };
    },
};
</script>
```

When I click on the shortcut - I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.setRefreshRateVisibility is not a function
```

When I do

```
<div id="DateTimePicker" @click="this.setRefreshRateVisibility(true)">
```

it works fine, so the problem is not with the action itself, but with how I invoke this action, I think. Here's the store file:

```
export default {
    state: {
        isRefreshRateVisible: false,
    },
    mutations: {
        SET_VISIBILITY(state, newValue) {
            state.isRefreshRateVisible = newValue;
        },
    },
    actions: {
        setRefreshRateVisibility: ({ commit }, newValue) => {
            commit('SET_VISIBILITY', newValue);
        },
    },
    getters: {
        isRefreshRateVisible: state => state.isRefreshRateVisible,
    },
};
```

Can anybody help me resole this, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You possibly seem to have a wrong reference to `this`. In JavaScript context, `this` refers to the immediate context, but Vue functions are tied to the context of the class/component.

To prevent this, copy the reference of this to another variable.

```
data(){
   let componentObj = this;
   ...
```

And then call the method using that reference.

```
onClick(picker) {
    componentObj.setRefreshRateVisibility(true);
```

Comment: Thank you! That did help.
Is this the "canonical" way to circumvent this? I can't find any directions in the documentation.

Comment: You can use an arrow function. `Onclick: (picker) => { ... }`

Comment: Like @Frank said, arrow functions dont change scope like other functions do.